# Grease pencil strokes wrong Z-Order

Tags: camera, grease-pencil

Both of these characters are made up of Grease Pencil strokes.
[image]

The left arm of the red character is clearly in front of the black character's body.
Unfortunately, the red character is rendered behind the black character completely, when moving the camera.

[image]

The red character's arm, as well as leg, should be in front. I have Z passes enabled, it still doesn't render properly.

[image]

Comment: I don't have too much experience with grease pencil, but, as far as I know the strokes have an order. Like who is on top of who. If I am correct, you have to select the stroke and then something along the lines of "bring to front". But yeah, IDK. If I am correct and you know how to do this then do it. If not, wait for an answer

Comment: @Akshay2005 Can't find such an option, and that would be pretty tricky to do everytime for every animation frame

Comment: in the Data tab (green squiggle) under Strokes, make sure that the Stroke Depth Order is set to 3D Location